# Is there any way to have a default invisible option that describes my `select` tag?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Basically i want to have the description of the `select` tag - inside of it (something like default `option` that will not be visible in the drop-down).

I think i saw this implementation somewhere but i can't remember where, any help?

This is what i mean:

[image: DEMO]

```
<fieldset>
            <select id="global">
                <option value="opt1">opt1</option>
                <option value="opt2">opt2</option>
                <option value="x" selected="selected">Select Your Type:</option>
                <option value="opt3">opt3</option>
                <option value="opt4">opt4</option>
            </select>
</fieldset>
```

The only problem is that i see the "labels" as options in the drop-down which i don't want to happen.

Answer (score 2):

```
<fieldset>
            <select data-description="This is a good description" id="global">
                <option value="opt1">opt1</option>
                <option value="opt2">opt2</option>
                <option value="x" selected="selected">Select Your Type:</option>
                <option value="opt3">opt3</option>
                <option value="opt4">opt4</option>
            </select>
</fieldset>

<script>
alert( $('#global').data('description') );  // This will alert the description using jquery
</script>
```

Do it like the cool kids do, use data-attribute attribute!

Comment: hmm. i really want to do it my way without any popups.. i could just add labels if i just wanted to do it "somehow".

Comment: @Ricardo you don't have to alert the description, I only put the alert around it to show you how you can access the stored information

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here.. How is that gonna help me? i need it to be shown in the `select` when the page loads (and not listed in the drop-down options), can you please point me to the answer?

Comment: Oh then I misunderstood the question, I just thought you needed to store it and show it at a later time. Maybe a `<option disabled="disabled">Description here</option>` would help you then?

Comment: It is just getting 'un-clickable' but it is still visible in the list.